# STM32F411 Discovery Has to connect to an external 3.3V to power up?

Tags: power-supply, stm32, 3.3v

I have an stm32f411E Discovery board and I'm working with it  well. After I use it to work with an UART module suddenly it can't not power up anymore. I have to connect its 3.3V pin directly to another external 3.3V pin so it can power up. Does anyone know why? Thank you

Comment: check the voltage at VDD pins after powering the board from USB. there might be a failure in the regulator.

Comment: yub i think that it's maybe the problem. Because the board can't turn on so there is no power in vdd pin. I double checked after powering from USB and there is no voltage. Do you know how somehow to fix this?

Comment: A quick fix is to use another 3.3V regulator and a diode at the output in series. The anode of the diode can be connected to the D3 diodes cathode.. thereby it will be an alternative source. ...replace U1 if you can buy one? Only after making sure that the U1 is the culprit

Answer (score 1):

Check the input and output of the voltage regulator U1, if the input is 5V and the output is 0V probably it's broken.

[image: Schematics from official site https://www.st.com/en/evaluation-tools/32f411ediscovery.html#resource]

Here is the pinout of U1

[image: Pinout of regulator]

U1 is here on the board:

[image: Board discovery]

Comment: OK. Thank you i will check it

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you **never** connect the +5 (or +3.3V) supply of your UART module with the development board.

The discovery boards create their own +3.3V supply from the USB port. So does the UART module. If you connect these positive supplies together, one of them will burn out. It's possible the regulator on your discovery board was destroyed.

Comment: yub. I think that's is exactly what happened. I screwed it up by doing that.Now i know why. Thank you